# How to create a partionned table in BigQuery using the web UI?

Tags: user-interface, google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a partitioned table using BigQuery's web UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 - Choose Dataset and click + or triangle icon

[image]

Step 2 - In `Partitioning` Option pick `Day`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

*Dataset* > *Create new table* > *Partitioning* > *None | Day*

[image]